# How much RAM needed for Server with 150 client?

Tags: apache-2.2, memory

We are running a intranet portal with Apache,MySQL, PHP on Win Server 2000.

Other detail:

1. User: 150
2. Also hosting video (Buffering issue)
   3.Server: Apache
3. Client PC: Windows XP

How much RAM is needed?

Comment: Need more details. 150 users at once? One at a time? What is the expected duty cycle of the server?

Comment: You're not helping us to help you Rahul - is this a physical or virtual server, if physical what make/model is it? how much memory have you got now? why the hell is it on W2K???

Answer (score 2):

"Apache, PHP and MySQL" tells about as much about requirements as "I have a car. How much gas I need for my 500 kilometer journey?"

If your PHP application just serves out lots of Hello World's, the hardware requirements for those 150 clients could be very low. On the other hand, if some heavy framework or a CMS is used and/or there are huge databases in use, then you need more spiffy hardware -- especially more memory.

Go on and install your intranet portal to some test environment and benchmark it with ab, siege, JMeter or some other benchmarking software. See how well it serves with various number of clients and requests (or, how rapidly it burns to ashes).

Answer (score 0):

If it is a VM, then start with 512Mb of RAM and increase if it turns out to be too little.

If it is a physical machine, then it depends how much memory the server will take, and your budget.  I'd be tempted to say max out the server capacity, or as much as you can afford.  Memory is relatively cheap, compared to downing your intranet to increase RAM.

Can't really say more without more specific details.